# gorm check for duplication in many to many relation

Tags: go, go-gorm

I have a many to many relations between chat rooms and users where a room can have many users in it. I want to check if the room with the same users exists before creating a room. For example, I have 2 users with ids 1 and 6 and I will create a room for them if there are no room has users with ids 1 and 6 I will create a room. Otherwise, no room created and return exists room

```
type Room struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID       uint               `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Hash     string             `json:"hash" binding:"required" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Users    []User       `json:"users" gorm:"many2many:room_users"`
    Messages []Message `json:"messages"`
}

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    ID       uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name     string `json:"name" binding:"required" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Phone    string `json:"phone"`
    Email    string `json:"email" binding:"required,email" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Password string `json:"password" binding:"required,min=8" gorm:"not null:true"`
    Gender   string `json:"gender" binding:"Enum=male_female" gorm:"type:gender;not null:true;default:male"`
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find any way to do that in GORM. I made some searchers and implement that in raw SQL

```
func (r *Repository) FindRoomWithUsersIds(ids []uint) (error, bool) {

    var result []Test

    err := db.DB.Raw(`SELECT room_id
                            FROM room_users rm1
                            WHERE user_id IN ?
                            GROUP BY room_id
                            HAVING COUNT(user_id) = ?
                            AND NOT EXISTS
                              (SELECT *
                               FROM room_users rm2
                               WHERE rm2.room_id = rm1.room_id
                                 AND user_id NOT IN ?)`, ids, len(ids), ids).Scan(&result)
    if err.Error != nil {
        log.Println("err2", err.Error)
        return err.Error, false
    }
    log.Println(result)
    return nil, len(result) > 0
}
```